# floor equation for fibonacci sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fibonacci-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was reading the book "*Famous Puzzles of Great Mathematicians*" and in page 13 it states that:

> Since the influence of the second term $((1-\sqrt{5})/2)^n/\sqrt{5}$ in the explicit formula for the nth term in fibonacci sequence $F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n\right]$ is negligible because $|(1-\sqrt{5})/2|<1$, it is sufficient to calculate the first term $((1+\sqrt{5})/2)^n/\sqrt{5}$ and round off the result to the nearest integer to obtain the exact(integer) value of $F_n$. To be more exact,
> $$F_n=\Bigg\lfloor{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\frac{1}{2}\right]}\Bigg\rfloor.$$

My problem is that I can't fill the gaps for example where does $+\frac{1}{2}$ come from? I saw [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529583/for-what-n-do-we-have-f-n-lfloor-frac1-sqrt5-frac1-sqrt52?noredirect=1) but the thing is that already assumes the solution and reverse engineering doesn't answer me.

Comment: If you want to round $x$ to the nearest integer (rounding half-integers upwards, as usual), then $\lfloor{x + 1/2}\rfloor$ is one way to express that.  Note that ignoring the small "second term" is only allowed because we know that $F_n$ is an integer.  So the large "first term" must, itself, be very close to that integer.  So for sufficiently large $n$, $\lfloor{x + \varepsilon}\rfloor$ will also be correct for any positive $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx For Fibonacci numbers if one drops the 1/2 then the floor is wrong for odd n. One must keep the 1/2 because the straight power of the larger root is alternately just over or just under the correct value..

Comment: @ coffeemath would you explain more?

Comment: The true value of $F_5$ is $5.$ When one computes $[(1+\sqrt{5})/2]^5/\sqrt{5}$ the result numericlly is $4.9959674...$ which after taking floor gives $4$ instead of the correct $5.$ The same keeps happening for larger odd numbers, but one needs a very accurate calculator which keeps more and more digits as the odd index increases.

Comment: Right, my point is that the value of the larger term becomes closer and closer to the true, integer value.  So while $\lfloor{x + 1/2}\rfloor$ is correct (and represents the rounding operation in general), $\lfloor{x + \varepsilon}\rfloor$ is also correct for smaller values with $0 < \varepsilon < 1/2$.  In particular, $\lfloor{x + 1/3}\rfloor$ is always correct.  And $\lfloor{x + 1/100}\rfloor$ is correct for all $n \ge 9$.  (@coffeemath is absolutely right that you cannot entirely drop the $\varepsilon$.)

Comment: @mjqxxxx Yes. smaller $\varepsilon$ work, and I think any specific positive $\varepsilon$ will work beyond some approriate index.

Answer (score 1):

> $$F_n=\Bigg\lfloor{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\frac{1}{2}\right]}\Bigg\rfloor$$

That looks odd... As the comment says, the second term in Binet's formula is small and can be neglected, i.e.

$$
F_n \approx
\frac1{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n
$$

The estimate is good enough that it actually yields the Fibonacci numbers when rounded:

$$F_n = \left\lceil\frac1{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right\rfloor
$$
and then express rounding to nearest by the floor function:

$$\lceil x \rfloor = \lfloor x + 0.5 \rfloor$$

so that

$$F_n = \left\lfloor\frac1{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n +\frac12\right\rfloor
$$

To see why this works, take the 2nd term of Binet's formula and estimate it like

$$\left|\frac1{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right| 
= \frac1{\sqrt{5}}\left|\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right|^n 
\leqslant \frac1{\sqrt{5}} < 0.5$$

The un-rounded values are:

$$\begin{align}
F_0 &\approx 0.44 \to 0 \\
F_1 &\approx 0.72 \to 1\\
F_2 &\approx 1.17 \to 1\\
F_3 &\approx 1.89 \to 2\\
F_4 &\approx 3.07 \to 3\\
F_5 &\approx 4.96 \to 5\\
\end{align}$$
etc.

But your formula is adding $1/(2\sqrt5)$ which is odd...

Comment: I think that's book's error. is $\lceil{}\rfloor$ a standard notation or you defined it as above?

Comment: I've seen that notation before, where $\lceil\cdot\rfloor$ is rounding half-integer values up, and $\lfloor\cdot\rceil$ is rounding half-integer values down.